# Switched my shell to fish and now rails wont load a server. How can I get it running?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shell, fish

Ok, well I just changed my shell to use fish instead of oh-my-zsh.  I removed oh-my-zsh and everything got a bit messed up.  So I installed rails and bundle installed my application, but i'm getting this error when I try to load the server.

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:40:in `<module:Helpers>': uninitialized constant ActionView::Helpers::ActiveModelHelper (NameError)
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:4:in `<module:ActionView>'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/base.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/view_paths.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_controller/base.rb:204:in `<class:Base>'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_controller/base.rb:164:in `<module:ActionController>'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_controller/base.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/responders-2.1.0/lib/responders/controller_method.rb:37:in `<top (required)>'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/responders-2.1.0/lib/responders.rb:15:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/responders-2.1.0/lib/responders.rb:15:in `<module:Responders>'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/responders-2.1.0/lib/responders.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.9/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.9/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.9/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.9/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.9/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.9/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.9/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
from /Users/jay/current_projects/s/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

It's pointing `/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/` here, but I use rbenv.  I'm not sure if it should be looking inside of rbenv.

Comment: Uhm, yeah, `rbenv fish` in Google outputs a boatload of results... Namely, [this](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/issues/195).I use RVM, if it turns out to work, feel free to post an answer yourself.

Comment: Thanks, i've never really customized the shell much and have had zsh for over a year.  So when I tried fish and it was much faster, but I didn't really know why everything was broken.  Thanks for the link though, solved my problem.

Comment: Yeah, currently using zsh too, but considering a switch. Zsh with antigen rocks, but fish caught my attention with its "shadow autocompletion". If I can get to setting it up properly one day with these rvm, nvm and other stuff...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D-side gave this link above in a comment.

https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/issues/195

adding these shims to my config.fish fixed the problem:

```
set PATH $HOME/.rbenv/bin $PATH
set PATH $HOME/.rbenv/shims $PATH
rbenv rehash >/dev/null ^&1
```